# Nothing is displayed in localhost when I use the getday() method from javascript Date() class

Tags: javascript

When I remove the getday() method, the string is displayed, but when I add the method, even the string is not displayed.
The same thing happens in Firefox
Antivirus is disabled

Code :

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        d = new Date();
        switch(d.getday()){
            case 0:
                day = "Sunday";
                break
            case 1:
                day = "Monday"
                break
            case 2:
                day = "Tuesday"
                break
            case 3:
                day = "Wednesday"
                break
            case 4:
                day = "Thursday"
                break
            case 5:
                day = "Friday"
                break
            case 6:
                day = "Saturday"
                break
        document.write("<b> today is: ", day);                                                   
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu3fz.jpg)

I searched about this problem, but only one person had the same problem because he/she copied the codes from somewhere and the problem was solved by writing the code. I did not copy the code, so... please help me.

Comment: Please, when it's possible add code instead of picture of the code. Use proper tags for programming languages.

Comment: you have the document.write (first mistake) inside the `switch` block - syntactically incorrect, you must have an error on the browser *developer* console - surely (apparently not, but that document.write is after a `break` but not in a `case` so will never run

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri
Thank you very much for your suggestion and for paying attention to details
I corrected my mistake and my problem is solved

Comment: Your suggestion is correct
You drew my attention to detail. I have to write the tests regularly
But my code also works, the problem was with the getday() method
That's right getDay() "D"
camelcase
camelcaseeee!!!!!!
:D @JaromandaX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there were a few errors that I found in the code you provided.

1. you are using `d = new Date();`, but if you declare a variable, you'll have to use keywords like `const`, `let`, or `var`. Same with the `day` variable.
2. the `document.write()` statement is inside the `switch` statement.

after resolving these two errors, here is the updated version of the code:

```
<script>
  const d = new Date();
  let day;
  switch (d.getDay()) {
    case 0:
      day = "Sunday";
      break;
    case 1:
      day = "Monday";
      break;
    case 2:
      day = "Tuesday";
      break;
    case 3:
      day = "Wednesday";
      break;
    case 4:
      day = "Thursday";
      break;
    case 5:
      day = "Friday";
      break;
    case 6:
      day = "Saturday";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  document.write(`<b> today is: ${day}`);
</script>
```

Comment: Note that it is `getDay()` as shown here, not `getday()` as in original code

Comment: I compared your code with mine.
Your code is correct but mine also works
I did not follow the camelcase writing rules in calling the getday() method
getDay() is true.
Thank you for your time
Sorry for putting an image instead of code in this post. This was my first post

Answer (score 0):

I did not follow the camelcase writing rules in calling the **getday()** method **getDay()** is true.